# Display a text below marker on map using mapstraction

Tags: javascript, openlayers, mapstraction

Is there any way to display a text below marker on map using mapstraction?
I have tried `marker.setLabel("Test");` its not working am using  mxn-2.0.18 version

Regards,
Kiran V

Comment: I am also trying for same thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466238/mapstraction-show-text-below-marker)

Comment: I'm guessing that it was never actually fully implemented for OpenLayers: https://github.com/mapstraction/mxn/issues/136

Comment: @user1955010 Did you find that solution guys. I'm also searching related this.